# C# fetching host information from Skype user

Tags: c#, .net, ip, host, skype

I am working on a server infastructure that adjusts it's connectivity settings, according to the Ip address of my customers, for which my employees talk to over skype.

To be more time efficient, I feel it would be easier to use something similar to those Skype Ip address resolvers, in order to skip the process of explaining to each client "How to get their Ip address".

I work in the C# language if you need to know.

Comment: You want to grab the IP info from a user connected to your service or you want to grab the IP from a Skype user that might be the person using your system too ? Remember that the Skype allows you to be connected at many devices (smartphone, desktop, smarttv, notebook) at same time, so this would return false positive results...